# Marmalade - current build: x86 debug not found

Tags: c++, c++11, marmalade

I've just started using marmalade. I've set up all dependecies and head over to C++ tutorials. I opened up Stage1 and clicked 'Launch in simulator'. It gave me an error (pic in attachments). So I opened solution in VS 2015 Community and selected that it build for Debug x86. Then I tried build solution in VS but again, it gaves me lot of errors, mostly LNK2019 'unresolved external symbol...'. Back in Marmalade Hub it still gave me this: 'Current Build: x86 Debug (Not Found)'. Tough that maybe something is wrong with my pc, but I also installed Marmalade on my laptop and tried to solve that, but same stuff happens. I'm attaching some pic so you may know what it is about.

Also, I'm using Windows10, VS2015Community and Marmalade7.9 (with C++11 support).

Pics: [image]

Thanks for any given help!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. With your description it is hard to say what exactly is happening. "Lots of errors" problem cannot really be solved. Clarify your question. You might also want to know that the latest version of Marmalade as of Dec 2015 is [8.1](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/developer).

Comment: I've linked more image but someone deleted them. http://imgur.com/a/ir0cL Here is the link with all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile with Marmalade 7.9 (with C++11 support) you have to open mkb and add

> option {
>       cxx11 }

to compile all things.

If you don't need c++ 11 support, I suggest to upgrade to latest version (8.1), it's much more better and there's also a new version of hub available. It worked for me.